# Use of “past” in sentence

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> Would you be okay drinking milk that is few days past its expiration date?

I couldn’t understand how the past is used in this sentence . Is it adverb or preposition?

Answer (score 3):

**Past** here is used as a preposition, and means *"beyond in time; later than."*
[(Source)](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK834PK834&ei=m4_BXO6BN8OEjLsP5d2p4Ac&q=past%20meaning&oq=past%20meaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30l10.11583.12267..12638...0.0..0.308.1175.2-2j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.dAcvqX3X5II)
So in the sentence, it would a few days after the expiration date of the milk.

Comment: So, let’s say that i bought a bottle of milk and  its expiration date will pass three days later. Can i say “ milk will be three days past expiration date.

Comment: @languagelearner No, that is three days before the expiration date.